# How do I get the Scripts folder in the application bundle?

Tags: applescript

I'm really new to AppleScript so this is a real basic question but I couldn't find the answer or an example in the AppleScript ref. guide.

I'm making a simple script that I'll bundle as an application file, in the AppleScript Editor I can see the app's `Bundle Contents` in which I have an icon, a description file and a `Scripts` folder. How do I access that content from the script and how do I access the scripts inside the `scripts folder`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you save your script as a script bundle or as an application bundle you can use the `path to resource` command, e.g.:

```
path to resource "description.rtfd"
```

Also see [Commands Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html).

Comment: Great; to answer the 2nd part of the question: to get script file "SomeScript.scpt" from the "Scripts" subfolder, use `path to resource "SomeScript.scpt" in directory "Scripts"`.